# OpeningHandshakeException for Meteor Backend for Android app

Tags: android, meteor, websocket, reactive-programming

I've just learnt and implemented my first Meteor app with simple `meteor create hellometeor` command, then have used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to make `localhost:3000` port live.

Then I have used [delight-im/Android-DDP](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP) library to connect to the direct `ws` url as per the following code:

```
    // create a new instance, where mMeteor is a global var.
    mMeteor = new Meteor(this, "ws://180a3c0e.ngrok.io", new InMemoryDatabase()); // "ws://180a3c0e.ngrok.io" is the temp. url after tunneling `localhost:3000`

    // register the callback that will handle events and receive messages
    mMeteor.addCallback(this); // as the activity implements MeteorCallback

    // establish the connection
    mMeteor.connect();
```

But every-time I try to run this code, I'm getting the following error, for which I've found no suggestion or straight-forward solution, for a newbie like me in Meteor like platforms during the past 6hrs of googling and reading:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.Exception: com.neovisionaries.ws.client.OpeningHandshakeException: The status code of the opening handshake response is not '101 Switching Protocols'. The status line is: HTTP/1.0 502 Bad Gateway
W/System.err:     at im.delight.android.ddp.Meteor$1.onError(Meteor.java:195)
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnError(ListenerManager.java:432)
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ConnectThread.handleError(ConnectThread.java:50)
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ConnectThread.run(ConnectThread.java:41)
W/System.err: Caused by: com.neovisionaries.ws.client.OpeningHandshakeException: The status code of the opening handshake response is not '101 Switching Protocols'. The status line is: HTTP/1.0 502 Bad Gateway
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.HandshakeReader.validateStatusLine(HandshakeReader.java:232)
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.HandshakeReader.readHandshake(HandshakeReader.java:54)
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket.readHandshake(WebSocket.java:3113)
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket.shakeHands(WebSocket.java:2992)
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket.connect(WebSocket.java:2034)
W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ConnectThread.run(ConnectThread.java:37)
```

May be I'm missing a very common thing in the Meteor server-side, as I haven't code a single line in it, other than initiating the project.
Please enlighten me in this regard.
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should be crucified for not knowing that Meteor has its websocket connection at `ws://.../websocket` url.

I have just added `/websocket` at the end of the previous URL and everything is working just as smooth.